# Strange behavior of fields aligment in the structure

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct Foo
{
    char ch;   //1
    char ch2;  //1
    char ch3;  //1
    char ch4;  //1 _4
    char ch5;  //1
    short num; //2
    char ch6;  //1 _4
    int num2;  //4 _4
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {
    cout << sizeof( Foo );
    return 0;
}
```

Why output is 16 bytes? I thought that it must be 12 because :

```
4 char = 4 bytes  
char + short + char = 4 bytes  
int = 4 bytes
```

So can someone explain where are the rest 4 bytes?

Comment: The `short` is not only 2 big on your implementation, it also has alignment 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with **alignment**.

In short, CPUs prefer if different values are "aligned" in memory. For example, if you're dealing with a standard 32-bit integer (4 bytes), most CPUs will want it to reside in a memory address which is dividable by 4. So, memory address of `10004` will be OK, and `10008` will be OK, but `10005` will NOT be OK.

Most CPUs when dealing with unaligned values will throw an exception and refuse to process that. Our trusty x86 however is an exception to this and will process it correctly - albeit much slower. Behind the scenes it will fetch 2 aligned integers from the memory and then twiddle the bits to extract the misaligned integer from them. (On other platforms I think the compiler will generate extra instructions to do this work, but I'm not sure) So you **really** don't want this to happen, unless you've got a good reason for it.

And this is why your compiler generates some padding bytes between the `struct` members - so that the `short` would be in an even address and the `int` would be in an address that is divisable by 4.

The [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) can affect this, but only if you set it to less than `4`. And you'll get the alignment issues I mentioned before.

Comment: "Will process it correctly"? Only sometimes, atomicity can be broken by that.

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting is the following in memory (|s are 4byte boundaries):

```
|char char char char|char 1bytePadding short|char 3bytesPadding|int|
```

The `short` needs to be aligned to a 2byte boundary, so a byte of padding is inserted after the preceding `char` so that it can be. Similarly the `int` must be 4byte aligned, so after the `char` 3 bytes of padding must be inserted so it can be. If you are optimizing for space the rule of thumb is to order members from biggest to smallest. If you did so, it would be:

```
|int|short char char| char char char char|
```

which would take 12bytes, as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your structure with offsets:

```
struct Foo
{
    0:  char ch;   //1
    1:  char ch2;  //1
    2:  char ch3;  //1
    3:  char ch4;  //1 
    4:  char ch5;  //1
    5:  _padding   //1
    6:  short num; //2
    8:  char ch6;  //1 
    9:  _padding   //3
    12: int num2;  //4 
    16:
};
```

as `short` on your platfrom has 2 bytes alignment, there 1 byte padding added before `num` to make it's offset dividable by 2. Then there are 3 bytes after `ch6` to make offset of `num2` dividable by 4.